# Get every possible series of numbers based on two criteria

Tags: r

I have some data with two variables:

```
> x<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
> y<- c(50,51,51,52,53,51,54,55)
> data.frame(x,y)
  x  y
1 1 50
2 2 51
3 3 51
4 4 52
5 5 53
6 6 51
7 7 54
8 8 55
```

What I would like to find is every possible series of x values whose y counterpart increases with each number. X's must increase as well. Series that exclude numbers are ok if they don't yield an increase but no skipping numbers that fit. This data has 3 series of X's that work.

```
  x  y
1 1 50
2 2 51
4 4 52
5 5 53
7 7 54
8 8 55

  x  y
1 1 50
3 3 51
4 4 52
5 5 53
7 7 54
8 8 55

  x  y
1 1 50
6 6 51
7 7 54
8 8 55
```

Examples of 3 series that are NOT valid would be:

```
x  y
1 1 50
6 6 51
4 4 52
5 5 53
7 7 54
8 8 55
```

Invalid because X's are not consecutive.

```
  x  y
1 1 50
2 2 51
3 3 51
4 4 52
5 5 53
7 7 54
8 8 55
```

Invalid because Y's do not increase from 2 to 3.

```
  x  y
1 1 50
4 4 52
5 5 53
7 7 54
8 8 55
```

Invalid because it skips values that could fit.

Thanks for any insights you all have. Please ask me to clarify things if I was not clear.

Comment: The "longest subsequence" is a "known problem", and there is one implementation found at https://www.mango-solutions.com/blog/compute-longest-increasing-decreasing-subsequence-using-rcpp. Unfortunately, what you're looking for is "all subsequences", which requires a much more iterative and in-depth solution which will almost certainly not scale well. Can you explain what you are ultimately trying to do with these multiple sequences, or is that complicated?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your input. "Subsequence" was the word I was looking for here. My uses here are Bioinformatic and would probably take a lot of explaining, but my sequences will be fairly small, only about ~10 numbers. Thanks for linking the "longest subsequence" that will really help me think about how to tackle this. Thanks again!